# How do you specify a format for the input to date?

Tags: date

Given a date and time in a format that is not recognized by `date`, how can I get `date` to recognize the date and time?

For example:

```
$ date -d "09SEP2012:23:58:46"
date: invalid date `09SEP2012:23:58:46'
$ date -d "09SEP2012:23:58:46" --magic-option "ddMMMYYY:hh:mm:ss"
Sun Sep  9 23:58:46 MDT 2012
```

Does `--magic-option` exist? If not, is there a more elegant way to solve this rather than using `sed` to transform the input into a well-formed date string?

Comment: See also: [Date validation in shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/215659)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither POSIX nor GNU date have `--magic-option`. FreeBSD calls it `-f` (with a syntax similar to `date`'s output format specifiers, not the one you propose).

Your date is very close to being recognized by GNU date: all it takes is replacing the colon that separates the date from the time by a space.

```
date -d "$(echo "09SEP2012:23:58:46" | sed 's/:/ /')"
```

Comment: and with custom formats? Only way to go are regular expressions? this is horrible :-(

Comment: You can't parse dates without knowing something about the format they're in, the classical example being `01/02/03`.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a bunch of tools ([dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils/)) that deal with dates and times in a more script-friendly way.  Your magic option there is `--input-format|-i`, e.g.:

```
dconv -i '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S' "09SEP2012:23:58:46"
=>
  2012-09-09T23:58:46
```

While `dconv` does not directly support `date`'s output format (it doesn't confer `TZ` or anything in the environment), there's a tool `strptime` in [dateutils](http://hroptatyr.github.com/dateutils/) that does support the `%Z` format specifier.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using an environment like Ubuntu that has `busybox` installed, you can do `busybox date -D "$input_format" -d "$input"`, such as:

```
$ busybox date -D "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" -d "02/27/2013 23:48:00"
Wed Feb 27 23:48:00 CST 2013
```

If you want to format the output string to [something non-standard](https://xkcd.com/1179/) you can specify an output format with `busybox date -D "$input_format" -d "$input" +"$output_format"`,
such as

```
$ busybox date -D "%m/%d/%Y" -d "02/27/2013" +"%d.%-m.%y"
27.2.13
```

but for ISO-8601-compliant dates, use `-I` with the level of precision needed, such as:

```
$ busybox date -D "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" -d "02/27/2013 23:48:00" -Iseconds
2013-02-27T23:48:00-0600
```

### Notes

The [busybox man page](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html).
This [might not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494581/date-command-in-busybox-not-accepting-formatted-input-date) with `%Z` timezone format.

Comment: Thanks for this! This was the most helpful answer here as it usually doesn't involve installing any additional tools.