# Date validation in shell

Tags: shell-script, date

I want to validate the below date format in shell script

```
2015-Jul-13
```

I'm using `date -d "2015-Jul-13" +"%Y-%b-%d"` but its giving error as

```
date: invalid date '2015-Jul-13'
```

Comment: @Pandya: OP is clear about his/her question. OP wants to validate(check the entered date is valid or not) the mentioned date format but it is saying the entered date is invalid.

Comment: GNU `date` doesn't recognise `YYYY-MMM-DD`. Could you use `YYYY-MM-DD` or `DD MMM YYYY` instead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `at` does, and - I think - `touch` does as well. I wrote a date validation shell funvtion based on `touch` once... nope, not `touch` - it only handles numerals, but `at` does some pretty deep parsing...

Comment: @Thushi let's clear redundant comment by us

Comment: Misread the title: **Date validation is hell**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GNU `date` does not support `YYYY-MMM-DD`. However, it does understand `DD-MMM-YYYY`. So if you really have to handle dates of this format you can do it with something like this, which simply swaps the arguments around to a format that `date` expects:

```
ymd='2015-Jul-13'

dmy=$(echo "$ymd" | awk -F- '{ OFS=FS; print $3,$2,$1 }')
if date --date "$dmy" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo OK
fi
```

Here's an all shell solution. Breaking it down, the `IFS=-` instructions tells the shell to split a forthcoming command line by hyphen `-` instead of whitespace. The `set $ymd` parses the `$ymd` variable as for a command line, but now splits by hyphen, assigning values to the parameters `$1`, `$2` *et seq*. The `echo "$3-$2-$1"` trivially outputs the three captured values in reversed order.

```
ymd='2015-Jul-13'

dmy=$(IFS=-; set $ymd; echo "$3-$2-$1")
if date --date "$dmy" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo OK
fi
```

Comment: @mikeserv: Coolness! It worked with:

    ``ymd=$(IFS=-;set $ymd; echo "$3-$2-$1")``

Could you maybe reveal the magic behind the ``set`` command?

Answer (score 11):

From manpage:-

```
DATE STRING
       The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800"
       or  "2004-02-29  16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating calendar date,
       time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the
       beginning  of  the  day.   The  date string format is more complex than is easily documented here but is fully
       described in the info documentation.
```

But it seems not recognize `YYYY-MMM-DD` format. So, you can use either from below or similar like:

```
$ date -d "2015-07-13" +"%Y-%b-%d"
2015-Jul-13
$ date -d "Jul 13 2015" +"%Y-%b-%d"
2015-Jul-13
$ date -d "13 Jul 2015" +"%Y-%b-%d"
2015-Jul-13
```

OR you've to convert/[re-formate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215691/66803) it before sending to `date`!

Also see [How do you specify a format for the input to date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56824/66803)

---

I recommend to Visit: [**Date input formats**](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/coreutils-4.5.4/html_chapter/coreutils_27.html).

> Here are the rules.
>
> **For numeric months**, the ISO 8601 format 'year-month-day' is allowed, where year is any positive number, month is a number between 01 and 12, and day is a number between 01 and 31. A leading zero must be present if a number is less than ten. If year is 68 or smaller, then 2000 is added to it; otherwise, if year is less than 100, then 1900 is added to it. The construct 'month/day/year', popular in the United States, is accepted. Also 'month/day', omitting the year.
>
> **Literal months** may be spelled out in full: 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November' or 'December'. Literal months may be abbreviated to their first three letters, possibly followed by an abbreviating dot. It is also permitted to write 'Sept' instead of 'September'.
>
> **When months are written literally**, the calendar date may be given as any of the following:
>
> day month year
>  day month
>  month day year
>  day-month-year

<sup>emphasized by me</sup>

Here you can see that there is no format like *year-month-day*! (for months are written literally)

Answer (score 7):

With `zsh` you could use the `strftime` builtin (available via `zsh/datetime`) with `-r` (reverse):

```
strftime -r format timestring
```

which uses *format* to parse the *timestring* and output the number of seconds since epoch:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
strftime -r %Y-%b-%d 2015-Jul-13
```

```
1436734800
```

This errors out if the date is invalid:

```
strftime -r %Y-%b-%d 2015-Jul-33
```

```
zsh:strftime:5: format not matched
```

You can also convert the seconds since epoch to any other standard/custom date format e.g.

```
strftime '%A, %B %d, %Y' 1447970400
```

```
Friday, November 20, 2015
```