# How can I convert 14/Jul/2015 into 14-08-2015

Tags: command-line, date

How can I convert `14/Jul/2015` into `14-08-2015`?

It is saying `invalid date format` because of the `Jul` element, but if I put `07` then it works fine.

I have tried this:

```
echo "Please enter the date: "
read X (here X is 14/Jul/2015)
a= date --date=$X '+%d-%b-%y'
echo "$a"
```

Comment: July isn't '08' :).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date validation in shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215691/100397) with particular reference to the solution that swaps around the field ordering

Answer (score 1):

If `$x` contains `14/Jul/2015`, then use this:

```
date -d "${x//\//-}" '+%d-%m-%Y'
```

It will print:

```
14-07-2015
```

The `date` utillity doesn't understand the slash separated string, so you have to remove it and replace it with a dash (`-`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with `Jul`, but with `/`, so remove them using for example parameter substitution mechanism:

```
echo "Please enter the date: "
read X
a=$(date --date="${X//\//-}" '+%d-%b-%y')
echo "$a"
```

Please note that your variable assignment was also wrong (there must not be space after `=`) and command substitution should be enclosed with `$()`.