# How to restructure a date variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting, text-formatting

I have a bash script that takes user-inputed dates in this format:
`dd.mm.yyyy` and saves it as a variable `$date`

Now I need to modify this variable to be in this format: `yyyymmdd` for further use.

So no more dots and back to front for the values between the dots.

Is there an easy way to do this kind of thing with `sed` for example?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56854/4443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pure `bash` solution:

```
$ # input is dd.mm.yyyy
$ input_date="dd.mm.yyyy"
$ # output will be yyyymmdd
$ output_date=${input_date:6:4}${input_date:3:2}${input_date:0:2}
$ echo "$output_date"
yyyymmdd
```

Comment: This worked perfect for my needs thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's my simplistic `sed` approach.  Not particularly clever but works :-)

```
$ IN=12.34.5678
$ OUT=$(echo $IN | sed 's/\(..\).\(..\).\(....\)/\3\2\1/')
$ echo $OUT
56783412
$
```

`awk` approach

```
$ OUT=$(echo $IN | awk -F. '{print $3$2$1}')
$ echo $OUT
56783412
$
```

`tr`/`tac`/`paste` hybrid

```
$ OUT=$(echo $IN | tr '.' '\n' | tac | paste -s -d "")
$ echo $OUT
56783412
$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "26.11.2016" | awk -F"." '{print $3$2$1}'
```

Output: `20161126`

Answer (score 0):

Or `awk`:

```
$ date=03.06.1990
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="."; OFS="" } { tmp=$1; $1=$3; $3=tmp }1' <<< "$date"
19900603
```

Comment: Or just `awk -F. '{print $3$2$1}' <<< $date`

Answer (score 0):

The `date` command can output in ISO8601 format, with a modifier:

```
robert@pip2:/tmp$ date
Mon Aug  5 16:09:35 PDT 2019

robert@pip2:/tmp$ date --iso-8601
2019-08-05
```

...then just remove the hyphens in between. Using sed:

```
robert@pip2:/tmp$ date --iso-8601 | sed s/-//g
20190805
```