# Bash script convert

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

i need to convert the text below in bash script

> 111319 2036

to

> 11/13/19 20:36

it's possible?

regards.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534033/how-to-restructure-a-date-variable-in-bash

Comment: It is possible. You'll use regular expressions and capturing parentheses, and put in the additional characters in the replacement part.

Comment: thanks, i got using: sed 's/^\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{2\}\)\(.\{3\}\)\(.\{2\}\)/\1\/\2\/\3 \4:\5/g'

Comment: @Lucas the right place for an Answer is below, in the Answer box; thank you!

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='2 2 2 1 2 2' '{ print $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 " " $5 ":" $6 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

The traditional solution would be to do something with `sed`

```
sed 's!^\(..\)\(..\)\(..\) \(..\)\(..\)!\1/\2\/\3 \4:\5!'
```

For example:

```
% echo 111319 2036 | sed 's!^\(..\)\(..\)\(..\) \(..\)\(..\)!\1/\2\/\3 \4:\5!'
11/13/19 20:36
```

There's also the possibility of a pure `bash` solution.

If, for example, you have the value in $a then

```
${a:0:2}/${a:2:2}/${a:4:2} ${a:7:2}:${a:8:2}
```

For example:

```
$ a="111319 2036"
$ echo ${a:0:2}/${a:2:2}/${a:4:2} ${a:7:2}:${a:8:2}
11/13/19 20:03
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "111319 2036"| awk '{print substr($1,1,2)"/"substr($1,3,2)"/"substr($1,5,2) " " substr($NF,1,2)":"substr($NF,3,4)}'
```

output

```
11/13/19 20:36
```